# T-SQL query to show all the past steps, active and future steps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables in SQL Server:

**map_table**: (workflow map path)

```
stepId step_name 
----------------    
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E
```

**history_table**:

```
stepId  timestamp author
----------------------------
1       9:00am    John
2       9:20am    Mary
```

**current_stageTable**:

```
 Id      currentStageId   waitingFor
 ------------------------------------        
 12345   3                Kat
```

I would like to write a query to show the map with the workflow status. Like this result here:

```
step   name  time     author
----------------------------    
 1      A    9:00am    John
 2      B    9:20am    Mary
 3      C    waiting   Kat
 4      D    
 5      E
```

I tried left join

```
select 
    m.stepId, m.step_name, h.timestamp, h.author
from  
    map_table m
left join  
    history_table h on m.stepId = h.stepId
```

I thought it will list all the records from the map table, since I am using left join, but somehow it only shows 3 records which is from history table..

So I changed to

```
select 
    m.stepId, m.step_name, h.timestamp, h.author
from 
    map_table m
left join 
    history_table h on m.stepId = h.stepId

union

select 
    m.stepId, m.step_name, '' as timestamp, '' as author
from 
    map_table m
where 
    m.stageId not in (select stageId from history_table)
order by 
    m.stepId
```

Then it list the result almost as I expected, but how do I add the 3rd table in to show the current active stage?

Thank you very much for all your help!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's what you asked:

```
with map_table as (
    select * from (values (1,'A')
    ,(2,'B')
    ,(3,'C')
    ,(4,'D')
    ,(5,'E')) t(stepId, step_name)
)
, history_table as (
    select * from (values 
    (1,'9:00am','John')
    ,(2,'9:20am','Mary')) t(stepId, timestamp, author)
)
, current_stapeTable as (
    select * from (values (2345, 3, 'Kat')) t(Id, currentStageId, waitingFor)
)

select
    m.stepId, m.step_name
    , time = coalesce(h.timestamp, case when c.waitingFor is not null then 'waiting' end)
    , author = coalesce(h.author, c.waitingFor)
from
    map_table m
    left join history_table h on m.stepId = h.stepId
    left join current_stapeTable c on m.stepId = c.currentStageId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a union fits well with the data and avoids the coalescing the values on multiple joins.

```
with timeline as (
    select stepId, "timestamp" as ts, author from history_table
    union all
    select currentStageId, 'waiting', waitingFor from current_stageTable
)
select step_id, step_name, "timestamp", author
from
    map_table as m left outer join timeline as t
        on t.stepId = m.stepId
```